# Can I move the inline style of a control to a different file?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So I have a StackPanel hat looks like this.

```
<StackPanel Width="100"
                        Height="100"
                        Background="#212121"
                        x:Name="Box"
                        ZIndex="1" Margin="-48,168,146,151">

                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=theMenuButton}" Value="True">
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slideRight}" />
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slideLeft}" />
                                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>

                <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform />
                </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            </StackPanel>
```

As you can see it's very cluttered and I would to minimize that.
Is there a way I could create like a ResourceDirectory and reference that to the style to minimize on the clutterness?

So to be clear, I want to move the `<StackPanel.Style...` into a seperate file and use that file to reference the style for the StackPanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

You do exactly what you just said, moving the `Style` tag into a resource dictionary (giving it a `x:Key` in the process). You then have to merge that dictionary into the visual tree so it is accessible to this `StackPanel`:

```
<!-- Use whatever parent of the stack panel. "Window" is an example -->
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           <ResourceDictionary Source="relativePathToYourDictionary"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then you just reference your style:

```
<StackPanel Style="{StaticResource YourStyleKey}"/>
```

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind explaining the comment *<!-- Use whatever parent instead of "Window" -->*

Comment: @Mark This could be on `Window`, `Application`, or even `UserControl`. You can merge into any parent of the desired stack panel

Comment: Ohh okay, I've done that and now I get this error, I had this earlier but I forgot what I did to fix it
https://i.imgur.com/9Xg1ZKA.png

Comment: @Mark That indicates it cannot find your resource. Where are you merging the dictionary in relative to the stack panel? You could also try `DynamicResource` as it's requirements are looser, at a small cost of performance.

Comment: Yeah i tried DynamicResource and it didnt work, I have my style in the Dictionary1 (bad name but Its only for testing :P)
https://i.imgur.com/7Xb2sJB.png

Comment: @MarkDenom That looks right to me, I'd put a gist together and ask in the WPF room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf see if anyone spots something

Answer (score 1):

Steps to reuse the style in application.

1. Add a new file of type "Resource Dictionary" and paste your `Style`.
2. Add this resource to `App.xaml` file.
3. You may or may not assign the `Key` to resource.

   -If `key` is assigned then you have explicitly mention on control to use that resource

   -No key is defined, style will automatically applied to all controls of defined type throughout the application

Comment: You can merge the dictionary at any point in the visual tree (that the stack panel is under) and not using a key will only affect those children (of course, if you merge into App.xaml then it will be application wide)